# how to rollback leveldb to a previous state?

Tags: leveldb

I'm preety new to LevelDB. I need something like "rollback to a specific state", does LevelDB support that? After some search, I know that LevelDB does not support transactions, but it support snapshots. Can I restore my database to a snapshot?

My need is like this:

1. Initial state
2. Make some change to the database
3. If anything wrong, go back to initial state.

Answer (score 0):

LevelDB snapshot are not meant for reverting change but to allow other readers from the same thread to have access to a consistent version of the database.

One way to solve you requirements is to implement an transaction log yourself:

1. **Begin transaction** and *take snapshot*
2. *Log* in memory every key that is modified
3. Then **Commit**, release the snapshot and the *log*
4. Or **Rollback**, look up the every modified keys in the log and retrieve their initial value from the snapshot and set it again. Release the snapshot and the log.